# Extracting data from a table under conditions

Tags: list-manipulation, conditional

I have a very large table with two columns. Let's say the name of first column is E and the name of the second is P. How can I get the E values when P = 0.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
  tbl = RandomInteger[{0, 3}, {10, 2}]
  (* {{0, 3}, {0, 0}, {1, 3}, {2, 0}, {2, 0}, {0, 0}, {1, 1}, {2, 2}, {1, 0}, {3, 3}}*)
```

You have many alternative methods:

```
  Cases[tbl, {x_, 0} :> x] 
  (* or *) Cases[tbl, {_, 0}][[All, 1]]
  (* or *) DeleteCases[tbl, {_, Except[0]}][[All, 1]]
  (* or *) Select[tbl, Last[#] == 0 &][[All, 1]]
  (* or *) Pick[tbl[[All, 1]], tbl[[All, 2]], 0]
  (* or *) Pick[tbl[[All, 1]], # == 0 & /@ tbl[[All, 2]]]
  (* or *) tbl /. {{x_, 0} :> x, {_, _} :> Sequence[]}
  (* or *) tbl[[Flatten@Position[tbl[[All, 2]], 0], 1]]
  (* or *) tbl[[Flatten@Position[tbl, {_, 0}], 1]]
  (* or *) Extract[tbl[[All, 1]], Position[tbl, {_, 0}]]
  (* or *) Extract[#[[1]], Position[#[[2]], 0]] &@Transpose@tbl
  (* or *) Delete[tbl, Position[tbl, {_, Except[0]}]][[All, 1]]
```

all give

```
 {0, 2, 2, 0, 1}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot kguler. This is what I want to do.

Comment: @Thakshila, my pleasure. Welcome to _Mathematica.SE_.

Answer (score 9):

Something like

```
Pick @@ Transpose@largetable~Join~{0}
```

might do it.  Unless `0` should be the `Real` number `0.`  If you have both, then try

```
Pick @@ Transpose@largetable~Join~{0 | 0.}
```

*Edit*:
The above is the same as `Apply[Pick, Join[Transpose[largetable], {0 | 0.}]]` and has the same effect as

```
With[{columns = Transpose[largetable]},
 Pick[columns[[1]], columns[[2]], 0 | 0.]]
```

provided `largetable` is of the form `{{E1, P1}, {E2, P2}, ...}`.

*Edit 2*: Example

```
largetable = Table[{i, RandomInteger[]}, {i, 10}]
```

> ```
> Out[1]= {{1, 0}, {2, 0}, {3, 0}, {4, 1}, {5, 0}, {6, 0}, {7, 0}, {8, 1}, {9, 1}, {10, 0}}
> ```

```
With[{columns = Transpose[largetable]}, 
 Pick[columns[[1]], columns[[2]], 0 | 0.]]
```

> Out[2]= {1, 3, 5, 7, 8, 9, 10}

Comment: `Infix` has its fans, but will bewilder rookies.

Comment: @YvesKlett Thanks for the feedback.  In my own experience, `@@` etc. was confusing at the beginning, too.  But the advances in Help over the last several versions of Mathematica have improved that considerably.  One can select `~`, execute the menu command Help > Find Selected Function, and learn about `Infix`.  It seems natural to me to use it with `Join`, and I guess I forgot it's still somewhat arcane.

Comment: @MichaelE2, Thanks Michael. Could you give an example and show how to write this code. Because, I tried, but there is no result.

Comment: @Thakshila  Probably because there were two typos in the `With` version.  Fixed now.  This ONE way is more or less equivalent to @kguler's FIFTH way.

Answer (score 2):

Some other possibilities

Using kglr's data:

```
list = 
 {{0, 3}, {0, 0}, {1, 3}, {2, 0}, {2, 0}, {0, 0}, {1, 1}, {2, 2}, {1, 0}, {3, 3}};
```

Predefine `p` and `q` for easy comparability:

```
p = Position[list, {_, Except @ 0}];

q = list[[All, 1]];
```

Functions

```
ReplaceAt[q, _ :> Nothing, p]
```

{0, 2, 2, 0, 1}

```
MapAt[Nothing, p] @ q
```

{0, 2, 2, 0, 1}

```
ReplacePart[p -> Nothing] @ q
```

{0, 2, 2, 0, 1}

Answer (score 1):

Using kglr's data:

```
tb1 = {{0, 3}, {0, 0}, {1, 3}, {2, 0}, {2, 0},
       {0, 0}, {1, 1}, {2, 2}, {1, 0}, {3, 3}};
```

Another way, using `ReplaceAll` and `If`:

```
tb1 /. {x1_, x2_} :> If[x2 == 0, x1, Nothing]

(*{0, 2, 2, 0, 1}*)
```

Or using `SubsetReplace`:

```
SubsetReplace[Flatten@#, {x1_, x2_} :> If[x2 == 0, x1, Nothing]] &@tb1

(*{0, 2, 2, 0, 1}*)
```

Or using `SubsetCases`:

```
SubsetCases[Flatten@#, {x1_, x2_} :> If[x2 == 0, x1, Nothing]] &@tb1

(*{0, 2, 2, 0, 1}*)
```

Answer (score 1):

I am, also, entering the party and will be using the data from @kglr

Caution: the following is not the most normal way of doing it. Actually it's very far from that.

```
tbl = {{0, 3}, {0, 0}, {1, 3}, {2, 0}, {2, 0}, {0, 0}, {1, 1}, {2, 
    2}, {1, 0}, {3, 3}};
Lookup[AssociationThread @@@ Reverse[Transpose /@ tbl, 2], 0] /. 
 Missing["KeyAbsent", 0] -> Nothing
```

**EDIT**

Thanks to @eldo who pointed out in the comments the shorter and nicer

```
Lookup[AssociationThread @@@ Reverse[tbl, 2], 0, Nothing]
```

Comment: +1 - eliminate some redundancies: `Lookup[AssociationThread @@@ Reverse[tbl, 2], 0, Nothing]`

Comment: @eldo thanks a lot for spotting this. I updated the answer including this as well!